# Craft 3 Deprecation Error from Twig/Extension/Core.php. How to fix?

Tags: templating, craft3, error-message

I'm getting a deprecation error from not using `.all()` to query my elements:

```
Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.
```

This is usually very easy to fix because Craft normally tells you which template and line to add the `.all()` to.  However, when looking at the origin, I see:

```
/Users/Me/Sites/Project/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php:577
```

This is pointing to something in Twig's vendor library, which I obviously don't want to fix for updating reasons.  Does anyone know what this is referring to in my templates?

Comment: This is really difficult to spot. You could take a look at the stack trace to spot at least the URL route so get to know the root template

Comment: I know the root template because I'm on the page and see the error in the debug toolbar.  It happens on a couple of pages of mine, but I don't understand what it wants me to change in the template code. All my element queries have the `.all()` added.  The error doesn't appear on all pages though, and I can't figure out what's different between the templates to cause the error in some instances but not others.

Comment: I guess some of your `ElementQueries` are not executed otherwise the error would not appear. You can edit the source code and instead of creating a deprecated error you dump the Query so you can see what things are searched. Or you post your Twig so we can search for it. Besides that I don't know how we are supposed to help. It's like fishing without water

Comment: If it's any help: it is executed in a `twig_array_merge` function so likely  you are trying to `|merge` a `Query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I was trying to get a single image from a matrix block by `block.image|first` instead of `block.image.one()`. The code was in a macro that was used on several templates so those templates got this error.